# Вопрос по Python, и создание zip архивов с помощью zipfile

Tags: python, zip

Читаю A byte of Python и там была задача написать прогу, создающую копию важных файлов, после чего переносящую их в архив в указанной папке.

Задачу выполнил с помощью модуля import os
Но написали что можно попробовать сделать создание архива с помощью import zipfile.

Я смог создать zip файл с помощью этой библиотеки но не могу записать туда файлы, как записать файлы в zip архив с помощью модуля zipfile?

```py
import os
import time
import zipfile

source = ['C:\\Users\\PCuser\\Documents\\Folder']
target_dir = 'C:\\Users\\PCuser\\Downloads'

now = time.strftime('%H%M%S')
target = now + '.zip'

zipfile.ZipFile(target_dir + os.sep + target, "w")
```

p.s. я новичок, можете объяснить, если возможность есть?)

Comment: zipfile.write('file.ext'), а затем zipfile.close()? Удивительно, что как создавать файл  - вы сумели найти, а как в него писать - поленились?

Comment: ZipFile.Write разве не только файл вписывает? Мне нужно что бы он как-то смог вписать туда мою папку Folder(((